# trouble with URL encoding in mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I am making a kind of proxy type thing and I need to encode all the get query using my .htaccess file. Basically I want to silently redirect:

```
http://example.com/p/external.php?foo=bar
```

to:

```
http://example.com/proxy.php?path=external.php%3Ffoo=bar
```

except that that doesn't seem to be the case with the following line of code:

```
RewriteRule ^p/(.*)$ /proxy.php?path=$1
```

I've tried using the B flag and the NE flag but neither seem to make a diference, anything before the ? is been passed on but nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Have your **generic rule** like this with `B` flag:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+p/[^?]+\?([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^p/(.+?)\.php$ /proxy.php?path=$1.php\%3F%1 [L,NC,B]
```

This will rewrite `/p/external.php?foo=bar&abc=123` to `/proxy.php` with

```
_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]=path=external.php%3Ffoo%3dbar%26abc%3d123
```

Comment: This allowed me to pass on every parameter, which would work if I then reconstructed the query string in my PHP and appended it to the path string. However, it would be preferable to url encode the whole path and have it passed along as one variable if possible.

Comment: Apache automatically applies URL encoding on the target URI so I would suggest utilize that feature to your benefit and keep it simple.

Comment: ok can you try: `RewriteRule ^p/(.+)$ /proxy.php?path=$1 [L,QSA,NE]`

Comment: btw when I entered this URL: `/p/external.php?foo=bar&abc=123` with above rule I got `_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]="path=external.php&foo=bar&abc=123"` Is this not acceptable?

Comment: That's what I'm working with currently but what I would prefer is that /p/external.php?foo=bar&abc=123 is converted to proxy.php?path=external.php%3Ffoo%3Dbar%26abc%3D123
From what I understand that is what should happen by default but it's not, I'm getting very confused

Comment: Ok that was an interesting problem. See the update now, I believe it works now.

Comment: Thanks for the input, unfortunately that just gave me constant 404 errors and thats beyond me now so I wouldn't know how to tweak it to work for me

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42524/discussion-between-anubhava-and-cainy393)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^p/ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1\%26%2[L,NE]  

RewriteRule ^p/(.*)$ /proxy.php?path=$1\%3F%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Because it's not part of the rule's pattern match, and won't be captured by the `(.*)`.

Comment: This worked well to capture the first parameter as I wanted, but about a 2nd and 3rd parameter? How should I go about making sure the & signs are url encoded and therefore not treated as part of my url

Comment: @cainy393 See edit, you'll need to encode the query string **first** before routing to the proxy.php file.